# object array only printing the first element of the array to the console repeatedly, instead of printing each different element

Tags: c#

Currently I'm a student learning c# and the assignment I have to do is to create a text file and write some Data to it for a hotel Guest, for example

> Liam,10,0
>
> Ryan,5,1

The format to this is

> Name, Nights staying, Corporate Guest (represented by the 0, 1 is a regular Guest)

My problem arises when I need to read this file which I have done but then read the data and decide if the person on each line is a Guest or Corporate Guest and store this into an object array. So far I have completed this but when printing the object array on the console it will only print the first element of the array 8 times (this is the length of the array). Here is the code I have so far and any suggestions are appreciated.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO;
using static System.Console;

namespace File_Handling
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Variables to be used in file
            int accBalance = 1, NightsStaying = 0;
            string name;
            char CorporateGuest;


        try
        {
            // Creates file to open and to write to
            StreamWriter X = new StreamWriter("Guests.txt");
            // File will be written to : File Handling\bin\debug

            for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
            {
                WriteLine();
                Write("What is Guests name? : ");
                name = ReadLine();
                Write("How many nights are they staying? : ");
                NightsStaying = int.Parse(ReadLine());
                Write("Corporate Guest? (Y/N) : ");
                CorporateGuest = Convert.ToChar(ReadLine());

                if (CorporateGuest == 'Y')
                {
                    accBalance = 0;
                    X.WriteLine($"{name},{NightsStaying},{accBalance}");
                }
                else
                {
                    X.WriteLine($"{name},{NightsStaying},{accBalance}");
                }
            }
            X.Close();
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException )
        {
            Write("Couldn't find 'Guest.txt' File");
        }

  FileReader reader = new FileReader();
        reader.MainReader();
    }
}

public class FileReader
{
    object[] arr = new object[8];
    public void MainReader()
    {
        FileStream fs = new FileStream("Guests.txt", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
        StreamReader Input = new StreamReader(fs);

        string LineIn;
        string[] Fields = new string[4];
        LineIn = Input.ReadLine();

        while (LineIn != null)
        {
            int i = 0;
            Fields = LineIn.Split(',');
            LineIn = Input.ReadLine();

            if (Fields[2] != "0")
            {
                arr[i] = "Guest";
            }
            else if (Fields[2] == "0")
            {
                arr[i] = "Corporate Guest";
            }
            i++;
           
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
        {

            foreach (object element in arr)
            {
                if (element != null)
                {

                    WriteLine(element.ToString());
                }
            }
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: This is a **great** opportunity to learn about the **[free, built-in Step Debugger](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y740d9d3.aspx)**

Comment: Move `int i = 0;` **outside** of the loop.

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem may be with your while loop...

```cs
int i = 0; // this should be outside the loop
while (LineIn != null)
{
    Fields = LineIn.Split(',');
    LineIn = Input.ReadLine();

    if (Fields[2] != "0")
    {
        arr[i] = "Guest";
    }
    else if (Fields[2] == "0")
    {
        arr[i] = "Corporate Guest";
    }
    i++;

}
```

You are declaring `int i = 0` at the start of your while loop, so each iteration of the loop is resetting it back to 0. Try declaring the `int i = 0` outside of your while loop.

Comment: Just ran with the i outside the loop, this seems to print “Corporate Guest” more than 8 times for some reason.

Comment: @RyhsHudson That is a new question. You've asked why is the first array location written repeatedly, and Fraser has answered that.

Comment: @RhysHudson: Notice that you've got nested loops on your output: one which repeats 8 times explicitly, and one which outputs everything in your array 8 times. So I'd expect to see 64 separate outputs.

Answer (score 0):

In your `while` loop, you initialize `i` to 0 each and every iteration. That means that every time you assign either "Guest" or "Corporate Guest" to your object array, you are only ever putting in the first element of the array. Try moving the declaration of `i` to just above the start of the loop like this:

```
int i = 0; // This should go first
while (LineIn != null)
{
  Fields = LineIn.Split(',');
  LineIn = Input.ReadLine();

  if (Fields[2] != "0")
  {
    arr[i] = "Guest";
  }
  else if (Fields[2] == "0")
  {
    arr[i] = "Corporate Guest";
  }
  i++;
}
```

After that, when you are reading the file, you have a nested loop. You are looping 8 times and then on each of those iterations, you loop over each element in the array. Try just a single loop to loop over each element:

```
// No for loop here
foreach (object element in arr)
{
  if (element != null)
  {
    WriteLine(element.ToString());
  }
}
```

I hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

There is actually 2 things that should be reviewed.

1. As has been stated in previous answers/comments, you are re-declaring (and initializing to zero) the index variable in the **while** loop which causes that only the first (zero) array position is updated:

```
int i = 0; // This was extracted from inside the loop. 
while (LineIn != null)
{ 
   // Code omitted...
}
```

2. When displaying the array to the console, you will be displaying the array content 8 times, since you have a **for** loop counting from 0 to 8 and then have the **foreach** loop interacting over the array. You should have only one of the loops:

```
// Either this:
for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
{
   if (arr[i] != null)
   {
      WriteLine(arr[i].ToString());
   }
}

// ... or ... this:
foreach (object element in arr)
{
   if (element != null)
   {
      WriteLine(element.ToString());
   }
}
```

I hope this helps. :)

Comment: this works in printing “Corporate Guest” to the console 8 times but doesn’t print the other 7 elements of the array since Corporate Guest is the first stored